# How to connect to host database from docker (Prisma)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have created a new (local) project with `prisma init`. But I cannot connect to my hosts `PostgreSQL` database. I have tried setting the host to :

```
host: docker.for.mac.host.internal
```

But when I visit the the playground all I get is the following `error` :

> Project not found: 'default$default

How can I connect Prisma to the database running on my local machine, outside of the container?

The full **docker-compose.yml** looks like :

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: docker.for.mac.host.internal
            port: '5432'
            database: mydb
            user: myusername
            password: ''
            migrations: false
```

Comment: Does this work in version `1.8.1`? What is your CLI version?

Comment: This does not work with 1.8.1 and 1.8.2. CLI version is 1.8.0

Comment: Did you deploy a default service? It looks like you are opening the `/` route which belongs to the default service. Can you visit the `/management` API? What happens when you `prisma deploy` a new service?

Comment: This is a local service so "docker-compose up" - then in a new window "prisma playground". I can access /management and run queries there - listProjects returns an empty array.

Comment: So it sounds like you haven't deployed a service yet

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried deploying first? in a terminal change to the directory with the **prisma.yml** and deploy your Prisma server 
`$ cd [dir of prisma.yml]` then `$ prisma deploy`